# Detect if div has contents that cause an overflow

Tags: jquery, html, overflow

We currently use the following code on our website to detect if a div has contents that cause it to overflow, and as such add a class to other elements:

```
// Resize ContainerHeader if a billboard ad is shown
var element = document.querySelector('#banner-top');
if( element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight || element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth) {
   // your element have overflow
   $('#banner-top').addClass('billboard');
   $('#a_ContainerHeader').addClass('billboard');
   $('.menu-header-container').attr('data-offset-top','430');
   //alert("YES overflow");
}
else{
  //your element don't have overflow
  //alert("NO overflow");
}
```

It works fine half of the time, but randomly doesn't seem to work. If we then refresh the page it will work again though! Very annoying.

Doesn anyone have any ideas why it wouldn't return true on occassion? There are no javascript errors in our console.

The code can be seen in use at http://www.onedirection.net.

Cheers,

Chris.

Comment: Just as a debugging test, if you wrap that code in a setTimeout with a 1 second delay, does it work consistently? If it does, then you're problem is cached images vs non-cached images. When they're cached, your code works, when they aren't your code breaks. preloading the images would be one way around it.

Comment: The content of the div is a banner ad which loads from an external network. In this case do you recommend a 1 second (or even longer) timeout, or is there an alternative method we could look at?

Comment: The purpose of the timeout is just to test for a race condition, it is NOT a solution. If the banner can take longer than 1 second, then yes the duration should be longer to test for said race condition.

Comment: In your opinon what method should we be looking at then?